# AWS RDS Postgres performance issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using rds(postgres) with instance type as db.m4.2xlarge.

Usually most of the time number of connections are 8-10. But on some occasion as the number of connections increases to 100-200. DB becomes non-responsive.

Queries which are being executed at max takes 2sec to execute.

My application server is running on django/python stack(with Gunicorn). Latency of these servers go high when DB server response time increases.

Any changes in configuration of postgres rds we should do to improve performance(currently most of the settings are default) ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.UsingMetrics do some investigation and post another question probably to http://serverfault.com/ not here.  Hope this helps

Comment: Presumably those 200 connections aren't idle, so the issue is more likely the query, not the connection. But you haven't provided any information on this.

Comment: Query doesnt seem to be issue as the same run perfectly fine on lower number of connections... Issue is only with higher number of concurrent connections.

Comment: Perhaps your queries are hitting the disk, and when many of them are running concurrently you reach the maximum IOPS that is provisioned for your database. Try increasing the provisioned IOPS as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS